# Wrapper for functions with similar but not identical signatures

Tags: c#, function, generics, wrapper

I'm using a third-pary API which has a number of distinct but similar HTTP-related objects such as:

```
TypeAService, TypeARequest, TypeAResponse

TypeBService, TypeBRequest, TypeBResponse
```

etc.

The pattern for the call is always the same, something like:

```
myTypeXResponse = myTypeXService.SubmitRequest(myTypeXRequest);
```

I need to wrap this line in some basic code which handles the specific `TypeXServiceException` by backing off and retrying and a few other details, about 10 - 20 lines of code which I have to type over and over again. I'm looking for some elegant way to wrap this line of code in a function which I could call by specifying the method which should be called and expected exception type, something like:

```
myTypeXResponse = myWrapperFunction(myTypeXService.SubmitRequest, myTypeXRequest, typeof(TypeXServiceException));
```

I tried having the function take and return Objects but in order to pass in a function I need to be specific about the function's signature which I can't do here. I feel like there is some way to do this with Generics but my research online didn't give me anything which fully answered my question.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generics to handle this:

```
public static T myWrapperFunction<T>(Func<T, T> func, T request)
    //where T : //some common base type, if it helps
{
    return func(request);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What would the call look like? Can you explain and/or refer me to some resources where I can learn more about the concepts involved?

Comment: @user2524845 It would look exactly like how you used in your example.  You can use Google to find sources of information on the related subjects; it's a fantastic resource.

Comment: When I tried this I was getting errors: **Error 7 'TypeBResponse TypeBService.SubmitRequest(TypeBRequest)' has the wrong return type**

AND

**Error 8 Cannot implicitly convert type 'TypeBRequest' to 'TypeBResponse'**

I changed the function header to:         **public static R SubmitTypeSpecificRequest<T,R>(Func<T,R> submitRequestFunction, T request)**

and it _seems_ to be working. Again, I'm new to generics so I don't know exactly what I did right or even if I did.

Answer (score 0):

The method Servy suggested to this problem (with the revisions in my last comment) has been working very well for some time, but I recently solved a similar problem with a different approach, using delegates instead of generics. I'll post it here in case anyone else can benefit from the code:

```
public delegate bool TryAgainAfterException(Exception ex);

public void RepeatAction(Action action, TryAgainAfterException tryAgainFunction)
{
   // set up whatever logic you would use for your do-while loop here
   bool tryAgain;

   do
   {
      tryAgain = false;
      try
      {
         action();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         if (tryAgainFunction(ex))
         {
            // the specific logic of the Exception
            // handling would go here, including:
            tryAgain = true;
         }
         else
            throw ex;
      }
   }
   while (tryAgain);
}
```

Now I can get my response object by wrapping the call inside of an Action:

```
RepeatAction( () => { myTypeXResponse = myTypeXService.SubmitRequest(myTypeXRequest); },
              e => e.GetType() == TypeXServiceException );
```

Not really advocating one method over the other, but I wanted to share this one as well.

Comment: If his answer solved your problem, why didn't you upvote and mark his post as the answer to your question?

Comment: @julealgon There's no responsibility to upvote, but yes it should have been marked as the answer

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ettiquite here, I never could quite get the hang of internet social conventions. But his answer was incomplete. He said the way he wrote the call was exactly what I needed but it only worked after I modified it according to my comment. So I wasn't sure whether that should be marked as the answer or not.